# print out following year if after a certain date

Tags: asp-classic

I am trying to find a way to grab the next year if the my form is filled out after a certain date in the calendar.
I currently have <%=thisyear%> in my code but want to try and add an if then statement that will grab the following year if after September 1 of the current year.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the DateAdd and DatePart function. your IF condition should just look like this

```
If DatePart("yyyy", DateAdd("m", -8, Date())) <> thisyear Then
    Do Stuff for after September 1
End If
```